Simba ODBC Challenge
I'm trying to use the Simba ODBC Windows driver to work with BigData. It connects and tests out fine in the ODBC Data Source Administrator. When connecting from Excel:
Unexpected error: Container exited unexpectedly with code 0xC0000409. PID: 23508.
Used features: Odbc.DataSource/Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery/3.0.7.1016/BigQuery/2.
Details:
    Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Container exited unexpectedly with code 0xC0000409. PID: 23508.
Used features: Odbc.DataSource/Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery/3.0.7.1016/BigQuery/2. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: >Container exited unexpectedly with code 0xC0000409. PID: 23508.
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ErrorTranslatingMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ErrorTranslatingMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ErrorTranslatingMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.Read(MessageChannel channel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.MessageChannel.Read()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IMessageChannelExtensions.WaitFor[T](IMessageChannel channel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.WaitFor(Func`1 condition, Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.TracingPreviewValueSource.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Preview.PreviewEvaluation.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<StartEvaluation>b__0(EvaluationResult2`1 result)

From MS Access ODBC Log
Oct 22 15:10:00.275 ERROR 11776 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLGetConnectAttr: [Simba][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 30002
Oct 22 15:10:00.276 ERROR 11776 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: [Simba][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 30002
Oct 22 15:10:01.203 ERROR 11776 Simba::BigQuery::GBQApiError::LogError: HTTP error: Not found: Table io-dashboard-380919:sql_server_dbo.MSysConf was not found in location US [code: 404][reason: notFound]
Oct 22 15:10:01.217 ERROR 11776 Simba::ODBC::ClassicQueryExecutor::DoCompleteExecution: [Simba][BigQuery] (31770) Table is not found. Not found: Table io-dashboard-380919:sql_server_dbo.MSysConf was not found in location US
Oct 22 15:10:01.219 ERROR 11776 Simba::ODBC::StatementState::DoExecDirect: [Simba][BigQuery] (31770) Table is not found. Not found: Table io-dashboard-380919:sql_server_dbo.MSysConf was not found in location US
Oct 22 15:10:01.220 ERROR 11776 Simba::ODBC::StatementStateAllocated::SQLExecDirectW: [Simba][BigQuery] (31770) Table is not found. Not found: Table io-dashboard-380919:sql_server_dbo.MSysConf was not found in location US
Oct 22 15:10:01.221 ERROR 11776 Simba::ODBC::Statement::SQLExecDirectW: [Simba][BigQuery] (31770) Table is not found. Not found: Table io-dashboard-380919:sql_server_dbo.MSysConf was not found in location US

From SQL Server Linked Server I'm not getting any tables returned back but don't have an error message.
I'm on the latest, 3.0.7.1016. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Hi @user10327557, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

I would check that the table exists.  The table being sought appears to be "io-dashboard-380919:sql_server_dbo.MSysConf".   This is the project "io-dashboard-380919" and the dataset "sql_server_dbo" and the table called "MSysConf".  I also noticed that there is an explicit request to look for this table in the region called "US".  Check that the dataset "sql_server_dbo" is also located in the "US" region.
